# Fedex Tracking Number

Tags: tracking, fedex

I need to integrate fedex api in my site. How can i get a  new tracking number for the first time regarding a shipping. I couldnt find a method to get the tracking number? Please help, if anyone knows.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you meant "**create a FedEx shipment**" when you refered to "**new tracking number.**"

FedEx has a developer program in which you can sign up and integrate your website with FedEx. Once you sign up, you can:

- Create shipments
- Cancel shipments
- Track packages
- Schedule pickup
- Create call tags
- Etc.

The link for FedEx developer program is: [http://www.fedex.com/us/developer](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/).

Best!

Answer (score 0):

The FedEx site for IE returns the webpage in an IFrame across another site. You can't cross sites for information with an Iframe. So instead do the following. You can transmit the following xml to: https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   xmlns:v10="http://fedex.com/ws/track/v10">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<v10:TrackRequest>
<v10:WebAuthenticationDetail>
<v10:ParentCredential>
<v10:Key>productionkey</v10:Key>
<v10:Password>productionpassword</v10:Password>
</v10:ParentCredential>
<v10:UserCredential>
<v10:Key>productionkey</v10:Key>
<v10:Password>productionpassword</v10:Password>
</v10:UserCredential>
</v10:WebAuthenticationDetail>
<v10:ClientDetail>
<v10:AccountNumber>accountnumber</v10:AccountNumber>
<v10:MeterNumber>meternumber</v10:MeterNumber>
<v10:IntegratorId/>
<v10:Localization>
<v10:LanguageCode>EN</v10:LanguageCode>
<v10:LocaleCode>us</v10:LocaleCode>
</v10:Localization>
</v10:ClientDetail>
<v10:TransactionDetail>
<v10:CustomerTransactionId>Ground Track By Number</v10:CustomerTransactionId>
<v10:Localization>
<v10:LanguageCode>EN</v10:LanguageCode>
<v10:LocaleCode>us</v10:LocaleCode>
</v10:Localization>
</v10:TransactionDetail>
<v10:Version>
<v10:ServiceId>trck</v10:ServiceId>
<v10:Major>10</v10:Major>
<v10:Intermediate>0</v10:Intermediate>
<v10:Minor>0</v10:Minor>
</v10:Version>
<v10:SelectionDetails>
<v10:CarrierCode>FDXG</v10:CarrierCode>
<v10:PackageIdentifier>
<v10:Type>TRACKING_NUMBER_OR_DOORTAG</v10:Type>
<v10:Value>$WAYBILL$</v10:Value>
</v10:PackageIdentifier>
</v10:SelectionDetails>
<v10:ProcessingOptions>INCLUDE_DETAILED_SCANS</v10:ProcessingOptions>
</v10:TrackRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Use the following VBA Code to transmit and it will return the tracking info:

```
Public Function ReturnXMLResponse(ByVal XML_Method As Variant, _
                          ByVal XML_Track_URL As Variant, _
                          ByVal XML_Request As Variant, _
                 Optional ByVal WaybillNum As String = "", _
                 Optional ByVal CarrierName As String = "", _
                 Optional ByVal TotalWaybills As Long = 0, _
                 Optional ByVal XML_Chunks As Long = 1) As String

 ' Passed expressions to this function have to be Variant, as some arguments
 ' may be passed as Null which would result in a type conversion failure.

' If True Then Exit Function
ReturnXMLResponse = "Test" ' default if not supported or not tracked by request
If UCase(XML_Track_URL) <> "NOT SUPPORTED" And UCase(XML_Track_URL) <> "NOT TRACKED BY REQUEST" Then
If (WaybillNum <> "") And (CarrierName <> "") Then
    TrackingCounter = TrackingCounter + (1 / XML_Chunks)
    SBText = "Tracking: " & CarrierName & ":" & WaybillNum
    If TotalWaybills <> 0 Then SBText = SBText & " (" & CLng(TrackingCounter) & "/" & TotalWaybills & ") [" & (TrackingCounter / TotalWaybills) * 100 & "%]"
    SBText = SBText & "."
    Application.SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, SBText
End If
Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("Microsoft.xmlhttp")
If (WaybillNum <> "") And (CarrierName <> "") Then
    SBText = SBText & "."
    Application.SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, SBText
End If
XMLHTTP.Open XML_Method, XML_Track_URL, False
If (WaybillNum <> "") And (CarrierName <> "") Then
    SBText = SBText & "."
    Application.SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, SBText
End If
XMLHTTP.Send XML_Request ' okay to send blank string, if not needed
If (WaybillNum <> "") And (CarrierName <> "") Then
    SBText = SBText & "."
    Application.SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, SBText
End If
ReturnXMLResponse = Cstr(XMLHttp.ResponseText)
End If
If ReturnXMLResponse = "" Then ReturnXMLResponse = "Nothing"
End Function

Basically XMLHTTP.Send XML_Request

'XMLHTTP.Send = Sending the XML_Request which is the soap envelope     
above.  It 'then returns the valid XML.
```

shareeditdel

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then flag / vote to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.* Duplicate answer found [here](//stackoverflow.com/a/39670952/2747593).

Answer (score 0):

You can find all type of tracking numbers in the link below.
I tested some of them. 
Response will not be exactly as it is written in dev guide, but It doesn't throw an error.
try another one and so on.

- click [this Link](https://images.fedex.com/templates/components/apps/wpor/secure/downloads/pdf/201607/FedEx_WebServices_DevelopersGuide_v2016.pdf)
- Go to the page 2014: Appendix AA: Test Server Mock Tracking Numbers
- You will see: [page with tracking numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaHiB.png). It worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 

When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.


While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.